# Trying to implement Tor protocols, why encryption is needed in some places?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, torproject.org

I'm trying to implement Tor protocol as a small project at school. I read the paper: https://svn-archive.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.pdf and related-docs. But there's a couple thing I'm questioning and can't find the answer yet.

1/ Why in Tor handshake protocol, public keys encryption are needed ? I understand that to extend relay to C through B, A need to encrypt the content with the B session key so only B know about C, preventing anyone snooping on the client gaining knowledge about the complete circuit A-B-C. But why also encrypt it with C public key ? It seems not necessary since the DH half-secret is supposed to be public, so there's nothing to hide, B can read the handshake package without problem. Even when handshaking A-B, I don't find it necessary to encrypt it with B public key for the same reason. Tor also doesn't need identification as TLS (which use public key for such purpose)

2/ Why do multiple layers needed when transporting data ? From what I understand, once the circuit established, each relay hold a circID table to figure out the next relay, so what is being transferred is only the destination package, so only 1 encryption with exit node session key is need to prevent anyone from knowing the destination ? Even if entry guard snooping, it only sees the encrypted destination package and nothing else, the only thing it can do is to send it to the next relay.

3/ The same when getting a response, why multiple encryption is needed ? It seems that 1 encryption with exit node session key is enough here.

Thank you all very much for helping.

Comment: Are you asking about link handshakes or circuit handshakes? The relay-to-relay connections have a [TLS + in-protocol handshake](https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/7cfcf176dcf97ed34c8976e117e15c3ca65c115e/tor-spec.txt#L197), and this is separate from the [circuit creation handshakes](https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/7cfcf176dcf97ed34c8976e117e15c3ca65c115e/tor-spec.txt#L1138).

Comment: I'm asking about the circuit creation handshakes. Tho, I also didn't understand why TLS was a requirement, it seems redundant.